# Temp variable used in select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I tried to retrieve data from the table using a temp variable. The temp variable returns correct data but when tried to use it in Query it is not returning correct data set.
I have tried retrieving data using hard coded temp value in the query, it works fine. Can anyone help me out to find the issue here.?

Below is my code I have tried

```
Declare @tempwordFinal varchar(50)                                     
select @tempwordFinal = ''''+'%'+'The Big Bang'+'%'+''''               
select @tempwordFinal --here the output is - '%The Big Bang%'

SELECT * from MasterProgram where ProgramTitle like @tempwordFinal --not working  
SELECT * from MasterProgram where ProgramTitle like '%The Big Bang%' -- working
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `@tempwordFinal` variable has single quotes at the start and end. So it expects the data in `ProgramTitle` column to have single quotes at the start and end. Except the wildcards whatever present inside the variable will be considered as data that's why it is failing.

```
select @tempwordFinal --here the output is - '%The Big Bang%'
                                             ^              ^
```

Try this way

```
Declare @tempwordFinal varchar(50)                                     
select @tempwordFinal = '%The Big Bang%'

select 1 where 'The Big Bang' like @tempwordFinal
```

When you use variables for `varchar` datatype we don't need single quotes. Single quotes are required only when you hard code the string constants

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with your (escaped) extra apostrophes. Like this `''''`.  You don't need those unless you are looking for words in the database which explicitly contain apostrophes.  The corrected code looks like this:

```
Declare @tempwordFinal As Varchar(50);

Set @tempwordFinal = '%The Big Bang%';

Select @tempwordFinal;  -- %The Big Bang%

SELECT * from MasterProgram where ProgramTitle like @tempwordFinal;
```

Comment: Please explain what this code do, do not drop code only like that.